# Anyone Know of a company that sells pixel bender filters?

Tags: pixel-bender

Anyone Know of a company that sells pixel bender filters?

Comment: What the hell is a pixel bender filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not many, but here are some companies that might server your needs:

http://www.plugsandpixels.com/pskiss.html

http://aescripts.com/category/plugins/

http://lacquer.fi/conduit/pixelbender/

...in addition to the already mentioned Pixel Bender Exchange site, which offers several free filters.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=productHome&exc=26&loc=en_us

or you  can create your own:

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/pixelbender/

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender/

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need to find professional produced filters.  Its a requirement for a project that I am working on they don't want me making the filters as silly as that sounds....